# How to create a dynamic SSRS Report

Tags: c#, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

i am doing a Lab Test web application Project.In this ,Customer will apply a order with list of lab Test.Once the lab test completed , i need to create a report with all the test conducted. The test will be different from each other.i can create a query for desired result.but the Table columns will be dynamic and number of tables(different test have different table) also will be dynamic.

As far as i know , we can create one static report format and bind the data table to it.or we can create a row group and colum group in matrix(i got from some links)and dynamically hide and visible the column.

my requirement is bit different and i can't make it static. is there any way to do this dynamic in SSRS Or any other tool ?. Or i have to go back to old school where i need to create report format(excel,pdf)in code(C#). Please advice some tips, Links or article which can solve this issue. help is appreciated.

Comment: You won't be able to do all that off a single report. Are you unable to create a report for each test type and call just the one you need?  You are right that column visibility can help, but not achieve everything. Can you give more detailed examples to help us further?

Comment: @Jonnus i hope you got my requirement. customer always need the report in a single file.so i try to find a way to achieve it.is there any way to hide and visible table like column in ssrs with parameter?

Comment: Yes, you can hide while tables if required (or charts, images). I #think# it's confusingly called "visible" instead of hidden, and is a property of the entire table

Answer (score 4):

As far as I understood your requirement, you need to have different tables(in regards to columns and style) for different tests.

For this you just need to add seperate tablix for each test (assuming you have limited number of tests) and then you need to set filters and visibilty expression on each tables based on specific 'test name'.

Just Right click on **top-left corner** of the tablix.

Click on **Tablix Properties**.

In **Tablix Properties** window:

Go to **Visibility** Tab for setting expression for show/hide the tablix.

Go to **Filter** Tab and add value and expression for filtering dataset.

I hope this fulfills your requirement.

Comment: Thanks hassan. but in my case i have more than 200 test.it may increase.so i can't follow this one.